# iPython didn't catch the empty line as a `\n`

Tags: python, ipython

It works in normal python interactive mode:

```
>>> """1
... 
... 2"""
'1\n\n2'
```

However, the second `\n` is gone in `iPython`

```
In [4]: """1
   ...: 
   ...: 2"""
Out[4]: '1\n2'
```

What's wrong?

Comment: weird! works fine with `%cpaste`.

Comment: Is it can be related to Python concept?? I think may be a bug in iPython

Comment: Works fine using iPython in Enthought but doesn't work in `cmd`. Weird.

Comment: This works fine on the `QT console` for me but misses the newline on the commandline console

Comment: It seems to lose all the empty lines (if there are more than one). Also, history commands show the wrong result being typed...

Comment: Temporary fix would be something like: `In [22]: '''1`
`....: $`
`....: 2'''.replace('$', '')`
`Out[22]: '1\n\n2'`

Comment: Temporary fix would be using `%cpaste`.

Comment: After viewing the source code, seems `ipython` catch each raw by raw_input which strip the `\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found that it's been solved in the newest version. Here's the [committing](https://github.com/minrk/ipython/commit/971cbb72fdda33cfa406d4392aabfd28224c5ef7)

The reason is that while `IPython` use `raw_input` to capture what use type, the `\n` is being stripped. And then the string will be append a '\n' later. However, if the string is an empty string, it'll be thrown out. The flow is like:

```
if not s:
    return
s = s+'\n'
```

Comment: Yep, input transformation is getting an overhaul for IPython 1.0.